# Inject ViewModel with Dagger 2 pre v2.10

Tags: viewmodel, dagger-2, android-viewmodel

I have a big project and I'm planning to inject ViewModel as seen on documentation:

```
@Singleton
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    val creator = creators[modelClass]
            ?: creators.asIterable().firstOrNull { modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key) }?.value
            ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")

    return try {
        creator.get() as T
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw RuntimeException(e)
    }

}
}

@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
@MapKey
internal annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)


@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
@Binds
internal abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(InitializationViewModel::class)
internal abstract fun bindInitializationViewModel(myViewModel: InitializationViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

But the problem I have is that I cannot find a way to inject on versions of pre-Dagger 2.10. I've tried to migrate the huge project to Dagger 2.21 with Android Injectors but I wasted 3 days with no success.

Does anyone achieve it?

Thanks